# IOS swift - Tracking used apps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm currently looking for a way to track user activity. I'm working on an IOS app using swift and i need stats of apps usage. basically I want to get-make a tracking of the used apps. Data like opened apps, start time and shut down time... I know that for get all stats, maybe is necessary run a backgroud service, but, this is another problem that i think to solve after. for now i want to know if it's posible, if there is some way to get stats for used apps. I know that the UIApplication class call the UIApplicationMain function when an app is launched. Maybe, from my app, there is a way for access this info?... Thanks, i have been a long time reading but really, i can't see some clear option.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to track the launch of other applications.  If that's the case, then you can't do it.  The answer Pixel gives below gives you some ideas about tracking usage of your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (as David has interpreted your question in the comments) you are trying to track usage of other apps that aren't yours, he's right; **you can only track your own app's usage**.

If you are needing to track events in your own app, there are a good number of analytic frameworks available to do exactly what you are needing to do.

[Flurry](http://www.flurry.com) is one I've used in the past with success, and is one of the more well know solutions. I've also utilized [Google's analytics framework](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/). Both are pretty straightforward to integrate into your app and to track the sort of fine grained events you are looking to capture. You can't go wrong with either one of those.

[Here](http://www.mobyaffiliates.com/blog/list-mobile-app-analytics-tools/) is a (slightly old) list of additional tracking/analytics options beyond Flurry and Google's offerings.

Comment: My dream is going down jeje... yeah, the idea was track the use of other applications.. But, now that i know that is not posible. Can you help me to know if is posible? 1. Track user calls? (telephone number and call duration). 2. Block de usage of other app? (for example, an inadequate app for children). 3. Track the usage of web navigators. (visited web pages) and block some "inadequate" web pages for children per example. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :(
1) Not possible. There are no relevant hooks into the phone to allow for this.
2) Not possible. Apps are sandboxed; you can't intercept other apps.
3) You won't be able to track usage of external web navigators, but you could embed a web view into your app and restrict certain urls in your app.

Comment: ok, thank you PixedcloudSt, now, i'm going to drink some beers.

Comment: PixelCloudSt, have you a link ot good tutorial for create the embed web view? maybe is necessary that the user only can use that.

Comment: I imagine there a ton of them if you do a google search. I don't have any particular one in mind off the top of my head. However, note that if you are targeting iOS 8 be aware that WKWebView replaces UIWebView ( http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/ )

Comment: @PixelCloudSt iOS 12 has new feature Screen Time. is there any way to get data from it ?. Please advice.

Comment: @HemantSolanki - I doubt it. Why don't you look into it and report back in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can record your feedback and user experiences, and bug reports with lookback.io